# Is asking about a movie IN a music video on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, identify, questions

My identification question [Movie from fragment in Cyndi Lauper's 'Time After Time' music video](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68299/movie-from-fragment-in-cyndi-laupers-time-after-time-music-video) about a movie featuring **in** a music video was put on hold as off-topic, citing the default link to the [what topics can I ask](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

That section specifically excludes *commercials and music videos*.

I can get that the amount of information in my question may have been insufficient (although indicating dialog, picture(s), period, country, and the 'journey into the desert' as one of the possible subjects), but I'm asking specifically here whether asking about movie fragments **IN** a music video is on-topic or not?

Comment: As long as an ID question contains as many details as possible, and is about a real movie\show (and not something that the video made up - this is crucial), they're usually fine by me.

Comment: (Actually, in [rare cases](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58730/what-is-that-movie-in-snc-movie-melody/), the video doesn't even have to contain a clip from the actual movie - but again, as long as the Q is detailed enough, that's OK.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it depends.  If said music video has enough of the clip to make it reasonable to find the movie, then it might be on-topic.  If there's not, then it's probably off-topic.